# деструктуризация props в typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В компонент приходит props.text, который имеет тип string. Пытаюсь избавиться от props с помощью деструктуризации. Но все попытки тщетны. Работает только вот так:

```
const FilterButton = (props:{text:string}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.text}
    </div>
  )
}
export default FilterButton;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выполнить деструктуризацию в typeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

описание аргумента делится на две части:

1. имя параметра (включая деструктуризацию)
2. тип параметра

В качестве типа указано `{text:string}`
В качестве имени указано `props`.

К `props` теперь можно применить деструктуризацию

```
{text}
```

В этом случае `text` будет иметь тип `string`

```
const FilterButton = ({text}:{text:string}) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

`type Props= {text:string}`

`const FilterButton  = ({text}: Props) => {}`